# Kendo UI ComboBox using angularjs takes time to display value on preview

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We are working with kendo ComboBox using angular js. We bind value to ComboBox using angularjs scope. On preview event, when we assign value on load time (fetched from database) to ComboBox, it takes time to display value on front side in ComboBox. As we marked on preview time, first it binds data to ComboBox and then display value. Is there any solution to display selected value/text on front side, whether the ComboBox get bound or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by applying value in the modal and setting the text accordingly.

Like Your model is `countryId` and have text value as `countryName` and name of the combobox is `countryComboBox` then you can use it like below:

`$scope.countryId = 1` (id of which you want to be displayed at first)

```
$scope.countryComboBox.value(1)
$scope.countryComboBox.text('INDIA')
```

it will initially set the text to `INDIA`.

Comment: is that you want to know or anything else?